# pause for user correction to input

Tags: c++, user-controls

I found this nice little snippet that pauses for the user, but it doesn't allow any choice. I would like to allow the user to quit or re-enter if he/she mistypes the input file name. Of course the program quits if the file doesn't exist but better to let the user make that decision.

```
void pause() {
cout << "Press ENTER to continue...";
cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
     }
```

Calling program snippet-

```
std::string name;
std::cout << "Please, enter your file name: ";
std::getline (std::cin,name);
std::cout << "Hello, " << name << '\n';
pause();
std::ifstream is (name.c_str(),ios::in | std::ifstream::binary);
```

Output for a bad file name -

```
Please, enter your file name: col.tat
Hello, col.tat
Press ENTER to continue...

file not found ---  col.tat

unix%
```

How can the code be changed to give the user the chance to re-enter the file name. I note that it's probably OK as is for a bad file name, but fails when the user inputs the wrong file name, yesterday's work for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::ifstream is;
do
{   
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Please, enter your file name: ";
    std::getline (std::cin,name);
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << '\n';
    pause();
    is.open(name.c_str(),ios::in | std::ifstream::binary);
} while (!is.is_open())
```

This will loop until `is` can open the given file.

Answer (score 0):

That logic is great, only thing is, the while in this case works like `

while (!is)

with that minor mod to your solution, it works and does what I want.`